# Spreading web sites onto more servers

Tags: iis, deployment, web-deployment, move

We have 200 customer facing web sites all on one server. They are all ASP.NET running in IIS. Is it possible to move some of them to another server WITHOUT changing the customer's URL? Any links explaining how to do this would be helpful.

Comment: could you please update the question how the each website urls are ? doe each website has its' own domain name? if so do you have this iis server setup with just static IP.  if all the websites use some common domain names(mail.example.com, www.example.com, sub.example.com ) it is more simple.

Answer (score 0):

If your sits are already registered to specific sub domains, you can simply re-point the names to the new server using dns.

If they are simply different sites under the same domain on IIS you can use your current IIS server to reverse proxy the new ones. Some info is given [here](https://serverfault.com/a/152411)

Lastly, you could consider using a load balancer such as netscaler, f5 or application request routing. You would again, point the domain name to this using DNS and the load balancer would send the requests to the correct server.